# Get emails after certain historyId using Gmail SDK

Tags: java, email, gmail-api

I have been through [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync) and I understand that I need to do partial synchronization.

The [history list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) after a certain historyId **returns all the actions** performed on gmail. But I need to get **only the messageId's** of the **new emails**.

How do I filter this or extract the new emails after a certain historyId?

Comment: @noogui I haven't really tried anything on partial synchronization. I am having a hard time to understand the response JSON of history list

Comment: Just look for history.list() that contain "messageAdded" in the response, right?  That will show things like sent and drafts (any message getting added to inbox) but that's the basic of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing it. The most that you can filter is to get all the history entries for a particular label and call only messageAdded history with the headers and check the recipient (To) in it.